# Applying SUMIFS() in excel

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to apply SUMIFS in excel but the second condition is not being applied:

```
A       B       C
abc     1       1
abc     1       5
abc     0       0
fgh     1       1
```

I am trying to get sum of column `C` when `A` is `abc` and `B` is `0`

I am using:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A4;"abc";C1:C4,B1:B4;"0")
```

but excel throws an error that the function is not valid. Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: `=SUMIFS(C1:C4;A1:A4;"abc";B1:B4;0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum_range comes first.

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C4;A1:A4;"abc";B1:B4;0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have approved an edit which changed SUMIFS to SUMIF by mistake.